# Error Deserializing Xml to Object - xmlns='' was not expected

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

I am having real trouble trying to deserialize some XML and was hoping someone can offer some assistance. I have read a lot of similar posts but I am unable to resolve this.

**XML I am attempting to deserialize**

```
<register-account success="false">
  <user-name>xxxxx</user-name>
  <password>fghgh</password>
  <email>test@example.com</email>
  <error>
    <errorcode>120</errorcode>
    <errormessage>The password is invalid</errormessage>
  </error>
</register-account>
```

**Class I am trying to deserialize to:**

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "register-account", Namespace = "MyNamespace")]
[XmlType("register-account")]
public class RegisterAccountResponse
{
    [XmlAttribute("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Tennant email address
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the tennant password
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Tennant username
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("user-name")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A Tenant Portal error relating to the RegisterAccountRequest
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("error")]
    public QubeError Error;
}
```

**Deserialization Method**

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string data) where T : class
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (data.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var sr = new StringReader(data))
        {
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }
```

**Deserialization Method Call**

```
var data = Helper.Deserialize<RegisterAccountResponse>(xml);
```

**Exception:**

> There is an error in XML document (1,
>   2). --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: was
>   not expected. at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderData.Read5_data()

**Inner Exception as follows:**

```
<register-account xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Simply take off the `Namespace =`:

```
[XmlRoot("register-account"), XmlType("register-account")]
public class RegisterAccountResponse {...}
```

since your xml doesn't seem to be in an xml-namespace. Also, `[Serializable]` isn't used by `XmlSerializer`.

If your xml was using a namespace it would have an `xmlns` at the root.

Also, to help with callers you could add `where T : class, new()` (the `, new()` being the addition) to your `Deserialize` method, since `XmlSerializer` demands a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: Marc you were spot on! I can't thank you enough as I had been tearing my hair out with this one.

Comment: Thank you so much! The extra info on the namespace was the solution I needed.

Comment: Could you please tell more about why the "Namespace =" in the class is needless?

Comment: @gfan because the xml in the question *does  not*  include that namespace; the xml and the model/deserializer *need to match*. Specifically, there is no `xmlns="MyNamespace"`, or `xmlns:someAlias="MyNamespace"`

Comment: FYI, this seems to work the opposite way as well.   Leaving off the namespace when a namespace is expected resulted in a similar error for me.

Comment: I'm dealing with cXML files that I generated classes via .dtd -> Vidual Studio -> XML -> Create Schema -> xsd.exe /classes. After removing the Namespace Attribute from everything I get a valid object tree. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked here for me

What worked is to MAKE SURE that the C# Class (main class) you are trying to map/deserialize the xml string to HAS AN XmlRootAttribute that matches the root element of the response.

Check my full answer with an exmaple  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525536/1594274

Comment: This was my solution also I had `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RESPONSE")]` instead of `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]`

Answer (score -2):

I found doing the following fixed this for me

```
if (elem.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi") == null) {
    elem.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
}

if (elem.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd") == null) {
    elem.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));
}
```