# Deserializing an XML document with the root being a list

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML document provided to me externally that I need to import into my application. The document is badly written, but not something I can really do much about.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xml>
    <Items>
        <Property1 />
        <Property2 />
        ...
    </Items>
    <Items>
        <Property1 />
        <Property2 />
        ...
    </Items>
    ...
</xml>
```

How should I go about using the `XmlSerializer` for this?
It doesn't seem to matter what class setup I use, or wether I put `XmlRoot(ElementName="xml")` on my base class it always says that the `<xml xmlns=''>` is unexpected.

**Edit: Added the C# code I am using**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "xml")]
public class Container
{
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public short S1 { get; set; }
    public short S2 { get; set; }
    public short S3 { get; set; }
    public short S4 { get; set; }
    public short S5 { get; set; }
    public short S6 { get; set; }
    public short S7 { get; set; }
}

public class XMLImport
{
    public Container Data{ get; private set; }

    public static XMLImport DeSerializeFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        XMLImport import = new XMLImport();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            import.Data = (Container)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return import;
    }
}
```

Comment: may be add a node `<list>` under `<xml>` and add all the `<Items>` in this node. since you are serializing it, hopefully it would be you who has to de-serialize it.

Comment: I mean you can then change the XML back to real (bad) structure after de-serializing if you really need it to be in this form.

Comment: I am getting this XML provided to me to deserialize it and add the data into my app. I am not serializing my data into XML. I prefer to not change the document at all prior to deserializing it.

Comment: Can you share your C# code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have a class `Items` maps to each `<Items>` node:

```
public class Items
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize your list of `Items` like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(
    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""iso-8859-1""?>
    <xml>
        <Items>
            <Property1 />
            <Property2 />
        </Items>
        <Items>
            <Property1 />
            <Property2 />
        </Items>
    </xml>");
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Items>), new XmlRootAttribute("xml"));
List<Items> list = (List<Items>)serializer.Deserialize(doc.CreateReader());
```

Comment: @Fung, Kindly ewview my answer below and let me know f I am wrong. Thanks. just for learning.

Comment: @Tauseef, It's hard to comment since you didn't provide your implementation. Try to write some code or modify answers from you links to solve OP's problem would be a good way to learn :)

Comment: :) thanks, Is it true that the xml has the root node `<xml>` as your code says `new XmlRootAttribute("xml")`. means there is a single root, not a list? yes, he posted his code upon my cooment.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your XML is not a List, **the root of your xml is the `<xml>` node** I think you are just confused by its name :)

please visit the following link, It has many good answers voted by many people.

Here is the link:  [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

[Error Deserializing Xml to Object - xmlns='' was not expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884383/error-deserializing-xml-to-object-xmlns-was-not-expected)

Simply take off the Namespace =:

```
[XmlRoot("xml"), XmlType("xml")] 
public class RegisterAccountResponse {...}
```

Comment: The root of my XML is a list of type Items. As I said, the document is badly written.

Comment: I think it is not possible to have multiple root elements in an xml.