# C# parse shoutcast XML error

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, shoutcast

I'm trying to parse XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<genrelist>
    <genre name="00s"></genre>
    <genre name="30s"></genre>
    <genre name="40s"></genre>
    <genre name="50s"></genre>
</genrelist>
```

I am using standard System.Xml deserializer, but I get an error: In document XML (0, 0) is error (my translation to english)  even before start parsing that XML is invalid. How to parse this XML?

Deserialization code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GenreList));
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/newxml.phtml", settings);
GenreList genrelist = (GenreList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: `but get error` and the error is...? Also, please show us your code.

Comment: Can you please include your C# code?  Just see if this post can help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884383/error-deserializing-xml-to-object-xmlns-was-not-expected

Comment: Error is In document XML (0, 0) is error (my translation to english)

Comment: @kasus, why did you revert my edit?

Comment: @Amy, I don't understand what about you say

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error when XML files from other systems have some weird char at the beginning of the file.

Make sure the file starts with below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
```

Sometimes it's worth opening the file in different editors to see if you can spot the rogue char.

Comment: It's ok, I see in Notepad++ with viewing special keys(CR, LF etc.)