# How to serialize my xml rows in to c# objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have the sample xml

```
 <ListingDoc version="1.0">
 <Areas>
 <Area Area_Seq="1" Area_Name="Mumbai" Area_Code="MUM"/>
 <Area Area_Seq="1" Area_Name="Delhi" Area_Code="DEL"/>
 </Areas>
<Companies>
<Company Company_Name="ABCD"  Company_Rating="5"  Company_Parent=""/>
<Company Company_Name="XYZ"  Company_Rating="12"  Company_Parent="ABCD"/>
<Company Company_Name="MAN"  Company_Rating="77"  Company_Parent=""/>
</Companies>
</ListingDoc>
```

and I want to use serialize this xml in corresponding objects using c#. but when I do this only alternate rows are coming in object. I used the code written below

```
   XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
   FileStream xmlFile=null;
   xmlFile = new FileStream("c://temp//Listing.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   using (xmlFile)
    {
       XmlNode n1= xmldoc.DocumentElement;
       XmlNodeList nodes = n1.SelectNodes("Companies");
       if (nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0)
       {
           //log session node found
           XmlDataDocument companyXml= new XmlDataDocument();
           companyXml.LoadXml(nodes[0].OuterXml);
           XmlNode Tag_comp = companyXml.DocumentElement;
           XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(Tag_comp);
           List<Company> companyList=new List<Company>();
            using (xmlReader)
            {
               while (xmlReader.Read())
               {
                   if (xmlReader.AttributeCount > 0)
                   {
                       System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Company));
                       var session = (Company)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                       companyList.Add(session);

                   }
               }
             }
        }
      }
```

This populates my list with alternative rows. Please suggest me something to fix it as I found that when I serialize my row then xmlreader advance to next record and I have used xmlReader.Read() in while loop also.

Alternatively I tried to use XDocument also. but it gave me error root element is missing so suggest me something .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you are doing to much yourself. Let the framework handle the XML to Object conversion for you all the way.

The following example uses a custom path (so change it), but it does assume your XML structure. This should give enough hints to continue on your way.

```
class Program
{
    const string filename = @".\Example.xml";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListingDoc), new Type[] { typeof(Company), typeof(Area) });
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // load from disk into object model
            ListingDoc listing = xSer.Deserialize(fs) as ListingDoc;

            // output loaded info
            listing.Areas.ForEach(area => Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}, {1}, {2}", area.Name, area.Sequence, area.Code));

            listing.Companies.ForEach(company => Console.WriteLine("Companies: {0}, {1}, {2}", company.Name, company.Rating, company.Parent));

        }
    }
}

public class ListingDoc
{
    public List<Area> Areas;
    public List<Company> Companies;
}

public class Company
{
    [XmlAttribute("Company_Rating")]
    public int Rating;

    [XmlAttribute("Company_Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlAttribute("Company_Parent")]
    public string Parent;
}

public class Area {
    [XmlAttribute("Area_Seq")]
    public int Sequence;

    [XmlAttribute("Area_Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlAttribute("Area_Code")]
    public string Code;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. but i am getting exception. exception message is "There is an error in XML document (1, 2)"  and inner exception is this. {"<ListingDoc xmlns=''> was not expected."}

Comment: Hi Marvin, Thanks alot. i resolved this issue.source :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884383/error-deserializing-xml-to-object-xmlns-was-not-expected