# Error in XML document (2,2)

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have some xml files and I am trying to deserialize as below in the given code.

```
using (StreamReader srFileContent = new StreamReader(filePath))  
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(messageType));   
    messageType objMessage = (messageType)serializer.Deserialize(srFileContent);  
}
```

Here file locate at filePath does not contains the following lines

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

and thats why I'm getting the error. Can u help me how to add this lines runtime before deserialize the stream of given file.

Error is given below:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
>   (2, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException:  was
>   not expected. at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadermessageType.‌​Read161_message()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader
>   textReader) at CCR2BB.frmMain.BWConvertProcess_DoWork()

Comment: You mean it's not a valid XML file? How *does* it start?

Comment: Does **not** contain those lines? Also, where's the rest of the XML file? Also, what's the error!?

Comment: Error is given below:
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <Document xmlns=''> was not expected.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadermessageType.Read161_message()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at CCR2BB.frmMain.BWConvertProcess_DoWork()

Comment: Are you possibly trying to serialise and deserialise different types?

Comment: The exception is telling you what is wrong.  It says:  "<Document xmlns=''> was not expected".  Your xml has a node called "Document" which does not match the type you are trying to deserialize into.  Can you show us the definition of messageType?  Could this be an issue of case sensitivity?  Or a missing namespace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [{"<user xmlns=''> was not expected.} Deserializing Twitter XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556874/user-xmlns-was-not-expected-deserializing-twitter-xml)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to look at the base exception to find out the problem. The exception caught probably contains 4 or more inner exceptions.

EG:

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution in another question was:

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "message";
// xRoot.Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(messageType),xRoot);
```

Maybe that's an approach for your problem. Because MSDN is down for my network I can't provide any more documentation for XmlRootAttribute.

Comment: I would like to give an upvote to the original answer, if you have a reference you could add to this answer that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

From where did you get the class 'messageType'?

If you have created xsd for your xml using xsd.exe and then using xsd you created this class.

Then your project will have two files which contain this class.

- One of the file is `designer.cs` which contains this class which is derived from `DataSet` class
- One file is simply a `.cs` file, which has a partial class.
- When you use this class while deserializing, it will refer to the class from designer.cs which is derived from `DataSet`.
- But if you remove designer.cs from you project, your code will refer to the partial class from .cs file.

By removing this designer.cs file, which had the class derived from `DataSet`, I was able to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to declare `XmlRootAttribute` for the class `messageType`. E.g.,

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "message", IsNulable=false)]

public class messageType 
{
...
}
```