# XML document error in MVC4 app

Tags: c#, xml

Getting the following error. Seems like there could be many possible reasons for this from other threads. I've kept my code as simple as possible.

```
    There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

    public class MovieSummary
    {
         public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }

    public class Movie
    {
         public int id { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
    }


    public static MovieSummary Deserialize()
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("c:\\movies.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MovieSummary));
            return (MovieSummary)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult GetListOfMovies()
    {
        MovieSummary summary = Deserialize();
        return View(summary);
    }

    <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    <movies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <movie>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>The Dark Knight</name>
     </movie>
    </movies>
```

Comment: Also: [Error in XML document (2,2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737892/error-in-xml-document-2-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root object is of type MovieSummary. So the serializer is expecting a root `<MovieSummary>` element. Use the XmlRoot and XmlElement attributes to rename your elements in the xml:

```
[XmlRoot("movies")]
public class MovieSummary
{
    [XmlElement("movie")]
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}


public class Movie
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your answer works. why wouldn't it work though, if instead I did indeed add <MovieSummary> as the root in my xml document? I got the same error when I did