# Deserialize from WebServices C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Here's my issue : I need to get a list of resources from a web services, and deserialize it into object. But it doesn't work, despite the facts my code worked with another xml file. So I can't figure why it doesn't work, and I'm stuck with that !

Here's the XML :

```
<ResourceDataSet xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/project/server/webservices/ResourceDataSet/">
<Resources>
  <RES_UID>blabla</RES_UID>
  <RES_NAME>blabla</RES_NAME>
  <RES_CODE>blabla</RES_CODE>
  <RES_GROUP>blabla</RES_GROUP>
  <RES_COST_CENTER>blabla</RES_COST_CENTER>
</Resources>
<Resources>
  <RES_UID>blabla</RES_UID>
  <RES_NAME>blabla</RES_NAME>
  <RES_CODE>blabla</RES_CODE>
  <RES_GROUP>blabla</RES_GROUP>
  <RES_COST_CENTER>blabla</RES_COST_CENTER>
</Resources>
<Resources>
  <RES_UID>blabla</RES_UID>
  <RES_NAME>blabla</RES_NAME>
  <RES_CODE>blabla</RES_CODE>
  <RES_GROUP>blabla</RES_GROUP>
  <RES_COST_CENTER>blabla</RES_COST_CENTER>
</Resources>
</ResourceDataSet>
```

The class I want to deserialize into :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace TestWPF
{   
[Serializable()]
public class Employee
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_UID")]
    public int RES_UID { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_NAME")]
    public String RES_NAME { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_CODE")]
    public String RES_CODE { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_GROUP")]
    public String RES_GROUP { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_COST_CENTER")]
    public String RES_COST_CENTER { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    { }

    public Employee(int r_id, String res_name, String res_code, String res_group, String res_cost_center)
    {
        this.RES_UID = r_id;
        this.RES_NAME = res_name;
        this.RES_CODE = res_code;
        this.RES_GROUP = res_group;
        this.RES_COST_CENTER = res_cost_center;
    }
}

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ResourceDataSet")]
public class EmployeeList //: IEnumerator, IEnumerable
{
    public EmployeeList() {Items = new List<Employee>();}
    [XmlArray("ResourceDataSet")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Resources")]
    public List<Employee> Items {get;set;}
}
}
```

And the code I use to deserialize :

```
EmployeeList lstEmployee = null;

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServersList));

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("testEmployee.xml");
lstEmployee = (EmployeeList)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
reader.Close();
for (int i = 0; i < lstEmployee.Items.Count(); i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(lstEmployee.Items[i].RES_NAME);
}
```

And when I try to launch I receive this error message :

[image: And when I try to launch I receive this error message :]

Comment: Hello, I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need the xml declaration at the top. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> (unless of course that's only a snippet. it would be good to see the rest if it is)

Comment: In fact, I can't modify the XML, because I receive it from a WeB Service that I call before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your xml file is invalid - RES_UID is expecting an int, so even when you get your serialization working you'll run into that problem.

You're also not taking into account the namespace.  The following class works:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Employee
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_UID")]
    public int RES_UID { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_NAME")]
    public String RES_NAME { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_CODE")]
    public String RES_CODE { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_GROUP")]
    public String RES_GROUP { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("RES_COST_CENTER")]
    public String RES_COST_CENTER { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    { }

    public Employee(int r_id, String res_name, String res_code, String res_group, String res_cost_center)
    {
        this.RES_UID = r_id;
        this.RES_NAME = res_name;
        this.RES_CODE = res_code;
        this.RES_GROUP = res_group;
        this.RES_COST_CENTER = res_cost_center;
    }
}

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ResourceDataSet", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/project/server/webservices/ResourceDataSet/")]
public class EmployeeList //: IEnumerator, IEnumerable
{
    public EmployeeList() {Items = new List<Employee>();}

    [XmlElement("Resources", Type = typeof(Employee))]
    public List<Employee> Items {get;set;}
}
}
```

and your calling code with the typos fixed:

```
EmployeeList lstEmployee = null;

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EmployeeList));

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("testEmployee.xml");
            lstEmployee = (EmployeeList)xs.Deserialize(sr);
            sr.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i < lstEmployee.Items.Count(); i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(lstEmployee.Items[i].RES_NAME);

            }
```

Remember to fix your xml to be ints otherwise it still won't work

Comment: Yes, it perfectly works ! I'll examine the changes you made to fully understand what was the problem, but thank's a lot, it's a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either decorate your root entity with the XmlRoot attribute or Or specify the root attribute when de serializing at runtime.

Here is a thread about this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557145/1305119

Comment: I decorate the root entity (see just above my EmployeeList class)

Comment: I think you should check the code... the Xmlserializer should be initialized with typeof EmployeeList.... XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EmployeeList));

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake with XmlSerializer initialization, but it doesn't work either with typeof(employeeList) ! I think there's a problem with my xml, but I can't see it.

Comment: I think the serializer is not able to locate the root... Try this....XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute("ResourceDataSet"); root.Namespace =the url in the xml; XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EmployeeList),root);