# "<ServiceConfig xmlns=''> was not expected error

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have a program that extends a base class like so:

```
namespace ConsoleExample
{
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("ServiceConfig")]
    public class ServiceConfig : BaseConfig<ServiceConfig>
    {
    }
}
```

where BaseConfig includes the following method:

```
        public abstract class BaseConfig<T> where T : BaseConfig<T>
        {
    ... 
            public void LoadConfig()
            {
                // Load configuration file
                ConfigReader<BaseConfig<T>> _configReader = new ConfigReader<BaseConfig<T>>(configFileName);

                _configReader.Load();
...
```

and ConfigReader is:

```
    public class ConfigReader<T>
    {
...    
               public Boolean Load()
                {
                    try
                    {
                            reader = new XmlTextReader(new StreamReader(_actualPath));
                            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                            deserializedObject = (T)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
                         }
                    }
        ...
```

and my XML is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ServiceConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

  <WindowTitle>Utility</WindowTitle>
  <LicenseKey />
  <BaseUri />

  <!-- Database connection information -->
  <DatabaseInfo>
    <ServerName>ABC</ServerName>
    <DatabaseName>XYZ</DatabaseName>
...
```

When I run this program I get the error message of `"<ServiceConfig xmlns=''> was not expected error`

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556874/user-xmlns-was-not-expected-deserializing-twitter-xml) that suggested adding the XMLRoot tag but that doesn't help.  I think it might be because the deserialization is coded in the BaseConfig program and somehow not interpreting the XMLRoot correctly but am not sure how to correct.

**EDIT:**

Solved this by creating ConfigReader object using just  (not BaseConfig) like so:

```
public void LoadConfig()
                {
                    // Load configuration file
                    ConfigReader<T> _configReader = new ConfigReader<T>(configFileName);
...
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel?  Why not just add a custom configuration section to app.config and let `ConfigurationManager` do all of the work?

Comment: @DStanley Can you explain further?  Not sure what I am reinventing.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this post I solved the issue by creating the ConfigReader using just <T> (See edit).