# Deserialize XML response from Web API into a console app

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

From a console app, I make a call to a Web API. The API returns an `IEnumerable<Foo>` as XML. The XML response looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfFoo xmlns:i="..." xmlns="....">
    <Foo>
        <Member1>First Foo</Member1>
        <Member2>Yes</Member2>
        ...
    </Foo>

    <Foo>
        ...
    </Foo>
</ArrayOfFoo>
```

When I try to deserialize it in the console app into a `List<Foo>`, it doesn't work. The exception reported is:

*`<ArrayOfFoo xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TheFooThing.Model'>` was not expected.*

Here's the code I use to deserialize the response:

```
string xml;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

// deserialize into shape IEnumerable<T>
var listOfFoos = new List<Foo>();
var resultType = listOfFoos.GetType();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(resultType);

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
using(var reader = doc.CreateReader())
{
    listOfFoos = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as List<Foo>;
}

return listOfFoos;
```

Note: I use the old `HttpWebRequest` to make the HTTP request and get a response from the API. No particular reason for choosing this and not choosing the `HTTPClient`.

Comment: Remove the namespaces from the xml string before passing it to `XDocument.Parse`.

Comment: Oh, there are already [some great answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556874/user-xmlns-was-not-expected-deserializing-twitter-xml) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that was generated with `DataContractSerializer` not `XmlSerializer`.  The former uses [`http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Clr.Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for its default namespace, whereas `XmlSerializer` does not specify a default namespace by default.  You could switch to `DataContractSerializer`, or pass the correct default namespace to the [`XmlSerializer` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string xml;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>), "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TheFooThing.Model");
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var listOfFoos = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as List<Foo>;
    return listOfFoos;
}
```