# Getting Generic List of C# objects from XML working fine, except when I put that in a List of Objects

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization, generic-list

This is working: (each Invoice has many LineItems)

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}

public class LineItem
{
    public int LineItemId { get; set; }
}
string strInvoice = "<Invoice>   <InvoiceId>12345</InvoiceId>   <LineItems>      <LineItem>         <LineItemId>123</LineItemId>      </LineItem>      <LineItem>         <LineItemId>456</LineItemId>      </LineItem>   </LineItems></Invoice>";

object result = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice)).Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(strInvoice));
```

Object gets deserialized perfectly.

But now, I try to make a List of Invoices (I now enclose the current XML string in `<Invoices></Invoices>`):

```
public class InvoiceList
{
    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

string strInvoices = "<Invoices><Invoice>   <InvoiceId>12345</InvoiceId>   <LineItems>      <LineItem>         <LineItemId>123</LineItemId>      </LineItem>      <LineItem>         <LineItemId>456</LineItemId>      </LineItem>   </LineItems></Invoice></Invoices>";

object results = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice)).Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(strInvoices));
```

resulting in:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 2).
{"<Invoices xmlns=''> was not expected."}
```

How can I structure my class or SQL to deserialize a list of Invoices?

Trying this - which is taken from the answer of the twitter question that was marked as duplicate, I get no results:

```
   string strInvoices = "<Invoices><Invoice>   <InvoiceId>12345</InvoiceId>   <LineItems>      <LineItem>         <LineItemId>123</LineItemId>      </LineItem>      <LineItem>         <LineItemId>456</LineItemId>      </LineItem>   </LineItems></Invoice></Invoices>";
    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xRoot.ElementName = "Invoices";
    xRoot.IsNullable = true;
    object results = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice),xRoot).Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(strInvoices));
```

If i do this, I get the same error:

```
object results = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice),xRoot).Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(strInvoices));
```

If I do this as comment suggested, nothing is returned:

```
 object results = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(InvoiceList),xRoot).Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(strInvoices));
```

It is thus different to the example marked as duplicate
I have gone through a lot of effort to duplicate this error and make it as generic and easily readable and copy-and-pasteable into Visual Studio as possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [{"<user xmlns=''> was not expected.} Deserializing Twitter XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556874/user-xmlns-was-not-expected-deserializing-twitter-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're deserialising to the wrong type - you want to deserialise to `InvoiceList`.

You should also add some attributes to your `InvoiceList` class to map the element names correctly:

```
[XmlRoot("Invoices")]
public class InvoiceList
{
    [XmlElement("Invoice")]
    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

And then you should be able to deserialise like so:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InvoiceList));

using (var reader = new StringReader(strInvoices))
{
    var list = (InvoiceList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/mBtPSP for a working example.

Comment: Added example of deserializing InvoiceList to OP, I then get no results

Comment: @PeterPitLock I've expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I applied everything like you said, but I get the "InvoiceList xmlsNS=" was not expected". I will add screenshot too

Comment: Your XML has no `InvoiceList`, it says `Invoices`.  The XML in your question works, I've tried it.  Are you using different XML?

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, I did change the XML from Invoices to InvoiceList, thanks so much Charles