# Error Deserializing SOAP Envelope using C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap, webapi, xmlserializer

I want to deserialize a soap envelope into an object generated by serviceRefernce tool in Visual studio, but i keep geting this Error :

```
<return xmlns='ns'> not expected.
```

My code:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(DirectoryPath + "xml_content.xml");

XName soapBody = XName.Get("return", "ns");

ServiceObject serviceObject = new ServiceObject ();

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceObject));

var xx = xDoc.Descendants(soapBody)
    .First()
    .FirstNode;

using (var reader = xx.CreateReader())
{
    serviceObject = (ServiceObject)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

A part of the Xml Content:

```
<ns:return
xmlns:ns="http://serviceretour.com" xsi:type="ax210:DepotIMRetour"
xmlns:ax2102="http://objetSocial.ic.dgi/xsd" >
<serviceRetour >
    <message xsi:nil="true"/>
    <succes>true</succes>
</serviceRetour>
<ax210:instructions xsi:type="ax210:ListeInstructionRetour">
    <ax210:serviceRetour xsi:type="ax210:ServiceRetour">
        <ax210:message xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ax210:succes>true</ax210:succes>
    </ax210:serviceRetour>
</ax210:instructions>
</ns:return>
```

What i'm doing wrong in Deserializing?

Comment: The xml is not valid.  From VS menu Project : Add New Item : XML.  Paste XML into view.  Errors will show in Error List like any compiler errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as suggested by [ask].  In particular, to help you we would need to see the XML and C# classes that generate the error.  Absent that your question doesn't have enough information to be answered.

Comment: But just as a guess, the element name of `xx` may not match the root element name for `ServiceObject`.  Maybe you need to add `[XmlRoot("return")]` to `ServiceObject` as shown in [{"<user xmlns=''> was not expected.} Deserializing Twitter XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557145)?

Comment: @jdweng The xml is valid, i already checked.

Comment: @dbc all the classes are generated by serviceRefernce from WSSDL File in VS, i'm not using custom classes.

Comment: Are you sure what you are sending is what you checked?  Error message says the XML is not valid.

Comment: @MedMofid - Is the XML shown in your question the content of the `xx` element?  If so, is your question "What classes can I use to deserialize this XML using `XmlSerializer` in C#?